# How to remove colorbox closing animation?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How to remove the closing animation on colorbox? My code below removes only the opening transition. thanks in advance.

```
$(".displayAddProducts").colorbox({
    inline: true, 
    width: "70%", 
    height: "50%", 
    transition: "none", 
    fadeOut: "0"
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `speed` property to be `0` : `speed:'0'`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `"` from the `fadeOut`:

```
$(".displayAddProducts").colorbox({
    inline: true, 
    width: "70%", 
    height: "50%", 
    transition: "none", 
    fadeOut: 0
});
```